# Missing something fundamental with my (first) setup.py - Python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, setup.py

I'm missing something fundamental with how my setup.py should look. I've tried many, many tweaks but to no avail. Please note that since I'm just doing an installer for just a single module, I chose to use `py_module = ['foo']` instead of `pacakges = ['foo']`. I tried `packages` with an additional `rss_parse` subdirectory as well, but still no dice. Clearly there's something from the docs that I either misunderstood, or missed entirely.

Directory:

```
~/rss_parse
  |- __init__.py
  |- README.md
  |- rss_parse.py
  |- setup.py
```

setup.py:

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(name            = 'rss_parse',
     version          ='0.1.0b1',
     description      ='RSS feed parser: Takes a URL and configuration dict and '
                       'returns an iterable object containing feed `<items>`',
     long_description = open('README.md', 'r').read(),
     author           = 'Alastair',
     author_email     = 'nope@nopenope.nope',
     url              = 'https://github.com/dev-dull/rss_parse',
     license          = 'MIT',
     py_module        = ['rss_parse'],
     install_requires = ['arrow', 'lxml'],
     classifiers      = [
     'Development Status :: 4 - Beta',
     'Intended Audience :: Developers',
     'Topic :: Software Development :: RSS and Atom feed parsing.',
     'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
     'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
     ],
     keywords         = 'RSS parser xml news Atom feed',
    )
```

*installing*:

`user@linux:~/rss_parse$ python3 setup.py install --user`

*testing*:

```
user@linux:~/rss_parse$ cd ~/Desktop # make sure python3 doesn't find it in ./
user@linux:~/Desktop$ python3
>>> import rss_parse
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'rss_parse'
```

Answer (score 0):

`py_modules` not `py_module`.

"There once was a woman from Venus..." - Lt. Cmdr. Data